# Filter keys of a type using another type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that will recursively exclude keys from one type if they do not appear in another. For example, given the two types:

```
type TargetType = {a: true, b: {c: true, d: true}};
type InputType = {a: string, b: { c: boolean, d: number, e: string }, f: number};
```

I want to create some generic type `PickMatchedKeys<T, U>` such that

```
PickMatchedKeys<InputType, TargetType> = {a: string, b: { c: boolean, d: number }}
```

Anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this? Here is my best attempt so far:

```
type PickMatchedKeys<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U ? PickMatchedKeys<T[K], U[K]> : never;
}
```

This works alright, but the problem is that the keys `f` and `b.e` still exist in `PickMatchedKeys<InputType, TargetType>`, but have type `never`. Ideally those keys would not be present in the final type at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
type PickMatchedKeys<T, U> = {
  [K in (keyof T) & (keyof U)]: 
    T[K] extends object ? PickMatchedKeys<T[K], U[K]> : T[K];
}
```

You don't really need conditional types to restrict the keys to those which are common to both `T` and `U`, since you can just intersect the key types.  The only thing you need to do is make sure not to drill down into primitives; that's where the `T[K] extends object` part comes in.  You should decide if you want some other criterion (e.g., do something special with arrays) but that's the basic plan.

Let's examine it:

```
type TestIt = PickMatchedKeys<InputType, TargetType>;
declare const z: TestIt;
z.a // string
z.b.c // boolean
z.b.d // number
z.b.e // error
z.f // error
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Never thought to use an intersection in the index type. I did have to add an additional case when `T[K]` is an array, since `object` captured it even though I didn't want to recurse into that. But with that addition, it works perfectly. Thanks!