# How can I restrict `TFieldName` to fields of a certain type with `react-hook-form`?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I have this `react-hook-form` component:

```
interface FormFieldInputLabelProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TFieldName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
> {
  control: Control<TFieldValues>;
  name: TFieldName;
}

export function FormFieldInputLabel<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TFieldName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
>({ name, control }: FormFieldInputLabelProps<TFieldValues, TFieldName>) {
  const { label } = useFieldContext();
  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    name,
    defaultValue: label
  });

  return <input type="hidden" {...field} />;
};
```

It works, but the problem is that I'm getting an error when trying to assign the `label` (which is of type `string`) to the `defaultValue` of that field. The error I'm getting is:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>>'.ts(2322)

I assume the issue is that `UnpackNestedValue<PathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>>` is not guaranteed to be a string... but I'm not sure how to deal with that?

Is there any way I can restrict these types, so that the provided `name` *is* guaranteed to correspond to a value which is of type `string`?

---

Link to codesandbox with the warning and expected usage:

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kare-38kdzm?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can you add a link to a StackBlitz with the relevant packages imported, so that it's easier to debug? I'm not familiar with these types, so I don't know which value your `UnpackNestedValue` error refers to.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoaePN) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: Created one on codesandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kare-38kdzm?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/2978)

Answer (score 1):

my first understanding was the same as yours, i.e. that as field values are

`export declare type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;`
they can still be of type `any` at some point. Therefore, the expected type for a given key is precisely something (because you give the path) but could be of anything… which mean we should provide a `TFieldName` extending only all the string values path keys.
While it is theoretically possible to [recursively filter all the properties of a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071711/filter-keys-of-a-type-using-another-type), and therefore also all the possible path of that type, I've not been able to achieve it within your example. Therefore, I doubt the problem to be coercing `any` values to a `string` value.

A possible explanation, is that the `TFieldName` could actually be empty, and TS knows it, this would result of a possible legal union type of `never | undefined` which are not string.

```js
export declare type UseControllerProps<TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues, TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>> = {
    name: TName;
    rules?: Omit<RegisterOptions<TFieldValues, TName>, 'valueAsNumber' | 'valueAsDate' | 'setValueAs' | 'disabled'>;
    shouldUnregister?: boolean;
    defaultValue?: FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TName>;
    control?: Control<TFieldValues>;
};
```

Therefore, unless you provide a minimum, non-empty `FieldValues` (I did not try) you probably need to type the label as follows:

```js
  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    name,
    defaultValue: label as FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>
  });
```

[Edit]

When the type is known, TS can infer properly the resulting type:
For instance: `const variable = PathValue<FieldValues, FieldPath<FieldValues>>`, `variable` is `any` because of the known `type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;`

But when we use a template like `TFieldValue`, TS cannot predict which value will be valid and seems to have restrictions coercing it properly. So, by lack of information i.e. not being able to simplify the type, TS keeps the original one which is `FieldPathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>` and therefore unresolved within the template.

[Edit 2] here is a [simple example to show the TS "limitation"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAYQgDsEBLGc09VAFX2AB46A+OAXjjrlBmDIBnOIJhRyJAOZwA-CLETpALjglgAN2BQA3AFgAUAdCRYcAGYBXEsiqlzVm9RIB1SgAsA4gK3lkTAMoQALbADAS8IPxC8uJScKwAFACUcADeBnCZcAD02YjAgmCU2JQA5MIQAEbq1BaCADTc-ogQBaoQ8BJmWjhu2HgEBhlZqMDw6pjk6JWjKsRklE60YcyBISvsXABEfaioEFsGAL5D+sbQ8JbWtiT2106uMG4QFjBeauLIyWnDmaPjk2mszg8woN2WjCYolikk2cC2AAlgHsDnp9EcgA)

Comment: Kind of annoyed there doesn't seem to be a way around it.  Would be so nice if it was possible to "link" this up somehow, so that I both could avoid the `as` _and_ could prevent passing in `name` pointing to incompatible value types. 

Comment: Very annoying, I tried something different this morning but still no luck (I edited the answer). It does not mean there is no way, but I'm not able to achieve it the way I thought.

Comment: @Svish I think there is no way (yet ?) for TS to do it, the conditions won't be coerced at all on a generic, even if that one extends an obvious type. See my [edit 2]